# Change text length based on screen size Media Query

Tags: html, css

I am recieving title value from api, its length can be from 10 to 100 characters.

Now if it's length greater than 21 characters then I need to show it like 21 char + "..".

Which I did using below:

if (title.length > 21) myTitle = title.substring(0, 21) + "..";

But now I want to change this condition > 15 char for @media (min-width: 320px)  {}

How can change using media query and update its length?

```
<h5  className="textTitle"> {myTitle}</h5>
```

Comment: If you want to execute JS code based on whether a specific media query matches: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: You can also subscribe to an event, to have ylur code automatically execute again, when the matching status of the media query changes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Testing_media_queries#receiving_query_notifications

Comment: If you don't insist on cutting this after a certain number of characters, but can also live with a pure CSS solution, where it shows as much of the text as possible, and then inserts "..." automatically at the end if necessary, you can also check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: @CBroe thanks, text-overflow: ellipsis worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use overflow elipsis and calculate the width of the control using REM, and then you would just use LENGTH_OF_THE_STRING_YOU_WISH_FOR. you can then update the width of the container to whatever you like based on media query. no need for javascript.